# Custom values in Maven pom.properties file

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I'm trying to add custom values in the pom.properties file that Maven generates in the `META-INF/maven/${groupId}/${artifactId}` location

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifestEntries>
                    <build>${BUILD_TAG}</build>
                </manifestEntries>
                <addMavenDescriptor>true</addMavenDescriptor>
                <pomPropertiesFile>${project.build.directory}\interface.properties</pomPropertiesFile>
            </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The content of the interface.properties files is

```
# Build Properties
buildId=746
```

Using the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/#pom-properties-content) I have pointed the `pomPropertiesFile` element to an external properties, but the generated pom.properties file still has the default content after running `mvn install`

What's the correct usage of the `pomPropertiesFile` element?

EDIT

I believe that the problem lies in org.apache.maven.archiver.PomPropertiesUtil. If you look at the method `sameContents` in the [source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/shared/tags/maven-archiver-2.5/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/archiver/PomPropertiesUtil.java?view=markup) it returns true if the properties in the external file are the same as the defaults and false if different. If the result of `sameContents` is false, then the contents of the external file are ignored.

Sure enough, this has already been [logged](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSHARED-154) as a bug

Comment: What does `interface.properties` look like?

Comment: It's a standard properties file.

Comment: Don't use "\" in Maven pom's. use the "/" instead.

Comment: Do not add the answer to the question itself. It is considered bad practice on StackOverflow. Instead, press `Answer Your Question` at the end of the page and put your answer there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to place a file under src/main/resources/META-INF/${groupId}/${artifactId}/interface.properties and let maven do the filtering job (configure the filtering). The file will automatically be copied to target/META-INF/maven/${groupId}/${artifactId}/ location.

Comment: This file is generated dynamically during the build process so I don't think that placing it in source tree is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4998

Maven 3 will resolve property placeholders eagerly when reading pom.xml for all properties values that are available at this time. Modifying these properties at a later time will not affect the values that are already resolved in pom.xml.

However, if property value is not available (there's no default), then placeholder will not be replaced by the value and it can still be processed later as a placeholder. For example, if a plugin will generate some property during the build, or if placeholder is read and processed by a plugin during some build step.